# Passing on parameters without activating turtle.onclick (Python3 Turtle)

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I need to pass on a parameter to an action set off by the `turtle.onclick()` without it auto-activating the click.

As of now, it functions, but it doesn't wait for the click. The code automatically runs as if it had been clicked, but it doesn't wait.

If I take out the parameter and run it with the parameter set as a global variable it will work, but we are not supposed to use the global space for anything but importing the turtle.

```
def click(string):
    turtle.onclick(draw(word))
    turtle.mainloop()
```

If I take out the (word) and move it to the global space it will wait for the click to run.

Comment: `turtle.onclick(lambda x, y: draw(word))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help you with your issue -- without more of your code, I can't write it in terms of your specific problem.

There are two salient items, first is defining the `clicked()` function within the `click()` function to lock your local `word` into a call back.

The other feature is the use of `onscreenclick()`.  Continue to use `onclick()` if you plan to click on the turtle cursor itself.  Use `onscreenclick()` if you want to click anywhere on the screen:

```
import turtle

def draw(word):
    turtle.write(word)

def click(word):
    def clicked(x, y):
        draw(word)

    turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)

click("Possible Solution")

turtle.mainloop()
```